# In Facebook Android SDK, How to fetch is_verified flag using GraphRequest?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk, android-facebook

We are trying to fetch is_verified like below:

```
GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.accessToken) { `object`, response ->
                                    Log.v("LoginActivity", response.toString())

                     }
                                val parameters = Bundle()
                                parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,first_name,last_name,email,is_verified,picture")
                                request.parameters = parameters
                                request.executeAsync()
```

Getting permissions like below:

```
  LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(
                        this,
                        Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email", "user_about_me")
                )
```

but is_verified flag value alone is not coming.

Comment: According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/ there is no field with that name.

Comment: @WizKid Thanks.. but they having that field in User Object, please check tabular column of User Fields listing in the same link which you shared.

Comment: The field is marked as deprecated, so it will stop working in some future API version. Graph API Explorer currently does not give me an error when trying to request it, but it looks like the field might not be included in the return data structure, if the user account was not indeed verified.